# Помощь с хандлером aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Возможно ли сделать в aiogram хандлер, который будет отлавливать сообщения только в личку? Мне нужно, чтобы это было как в pyrogram (@app.on_message(filters.private)).
Пример с if/else мне не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(types.ChatType.is_private)
async def ...
```

Этот метод будет реагировать только на сообщения полученные в личных сообщениях из-за `types.ChatType.is_private`.

По сути, тоже самое что и `filters.private` в pyrogram. Также можно добавить фильтр, к примеру для того, чтобы реагировать только на сообщения определенных пользователей.

```
@dp.message_handler(types.ChatType.is_private, my_filter)
async def ...
```

Comment: Объясните в ответе, что необходимо изменить, и почему это поможет в решении проблемы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Спасибо, дополнил.